# handling the first page and the last page of collection view pagination?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, rest

lets say, if my data is fetched from the server / api with an api call, how it is possible to determine the first page and last page of collection view data, meaning, if page == firstPage && is dataToFetch.isAvailable == true
isdataFetching = true
fetchData //( lets say 20 collectionView cells per fetch)

and if page  == lastPage && dataToFetch.isUnavailable == true
is fetchingData = false

how to accomplish the above logic in swift when fetching data from an api call?

So far, I have implemented the  `willDisplay cell` but stuck now here :

```
          func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: 
            UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
              if let response = response, let data = response.data, let content = data.content {
        
             if indexPath.row == content.count - 1 {
            call(page: data.number + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

my api call method looks similar to this:

```
              func APIcall(page: Int = 0) {
              NSLog("Call api")
             Server.getDatat(page: page).done { (data) -> Void in
        
        // handling  first page and  last page ..?

        self.response = data
        NSLog("Called api")
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }.catch { (err) in
        NSLog("\(err)")
    }
}
```

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is I want to fetch data 20 cells of collection view per fetching and disabling the fetching when fetching is no more available

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is check on every fetch if you have 20 elements (or the amount you want to get per call). If you get less than 20 elements, it means that you don't have more things to fetch so you could have a `var haveElementsLeft: bool` which in this case you would set it to false. And then check before making the network call if that variable is true or not. If it's false, the request should be ignored.

If you do have 20 it means 2 things: Either you still have elements to fetch from the server or your last call to the server gave you the last 20. Either way, you will have to make another call to the api to see if it was in fact the last 20 or you still have elements left.

Edit:

```
func getData(page: Int) {
    guard haveElementsLeft else { return }
    getElements(stuff: stuff, page: page)
}
```

This will only execute `getElements()` if `haveElementsLeft == true`.

Also you will need to count the elements you receive on your api call after you parsed them correctly so you can set the `haveElementsLeft` var to `true` or `false`.